# Is it possible to create a go (golang) binary that is instrumented for coverage for tests other than unit tests?

Tags: go, integration-testing, code-coverage

I've got some tests for my go project which are written in ruby/cucumber and I'm therefore unable to take advantage of the "go test"-based coverage tools to get coverage numbers for those tests (I also have unit tests and I'm happily generating coverage numbers for those).

Is there a way to create an instrumented build of go code such that I can generate coverage numbers for those non-go tests?

Answer (score 1):

No. You would have to write a ruby/cucumber interpreter in GO, write/adapt a coverage testing framework and then integrate that with the go test framework. 
Just rewrite the legacy ruby code in Go :P

Answer (score 0):

NO, but you can run go test in a way that creates coverage html pages.
like this:

```
go test -v -coverprofile cover.out ./...
go tool cover -html=cover.out -o cover.html
open cover.html
```